# How do you make overflow-y property account for an elements margin, without affecting overflow-x?

Tags: css, overflow, padding, margin

The `<main>` element on my page does not include the `margin-bottom` value of it's last element in the calculation of its content-box height. To fix this, I set the `overflow-y: auto`, now the margin of the last element is taken into account.

The problem is that this causes horizontal scrollbars on smaller screens. How do I only set `overflow-y`, without affecting `overflow-x`?

```
<main>
  <div>
    <h1>test</h1>
  </div>
</main>
```

```
main {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when the initial value for `overflow` is `visible`, changing either the x or y overflow value causes the other to become `auto`.

The fix for me was to use this rule:

```
main {
 overflow: hidden auto;
}
```

Posting this here because it took me way too long to figure out. Hope this helps someone.